# How to reverse letter capitalization in an NSString (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I was wondering how I would go about reversing the capitalization of the characters in an NSString or NSMutableString, ignoring non-letter characters.  For example, "HeLLO jIM66" would become "hEllo Jim66".

I know about uppercaseString, lowercaseString and capitalizedString but I haven't been able to figure out how to REVERSE the capitalization of ALL the letters in the string.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just iterate through all of the characters in the string.  If a character is uppercase, replace it with a lowercase letter; if it's lowercase, replace it with an uppercase letter; otherwise, leave it alone.  For example:

```
+ (NSString *) reverseCase:(NSString *)str
{
    int length = [str length];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        unichar ch = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        if (islower(ch))
            ch = toupper(ch);
        else if (isupper(ch))
            ch = tolower(ch);
        [result appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&ch length:1]];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be, it's a somewhat unusual operation.

Comment: Good answer, but I would opt for `[result appendFormat:"%C",ch]` instead of creating an `NSString` per char.

Comment: @Adam, I was clarifying for the OP :)

Comment: By default, `islower()` and friends will be operating in the C locale and may not work properly for non-ASCII characters. I recommend using `[[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:ch]` and `-[NSString lowercaseString]` and their uppercase siblings.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That's exactly what I needed. @mvds Thanks for that suggestion.  Good to know I don't have to create a new NSString each time.